# Transform raster values

Tags: r, random-forest, raster

I used this to predict values on a raster stack but the values then need to be back-transformed as they are log values:

```
r_pred <- raster::predict(model=rf_model, object=raster_stack)
```

I tried (but it did not work):

```
values(r_pred) <- exp(r_pred)
```

`Reclassify()` looks promising but I am not sure where to start?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Likely you can use `exp(values(r_pred))` for your transformation, but I can't verify that without an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: you can likely just use:

```
r_back_transformed = exp(r_pred)
```

The long answer is that from the `values` docs:

> In most cases it is better to use getValues rather than values. values
> is typically used in functions after a read* function has been used
> and it will return all the values that happen to be in memory at that
> point, or fail if there are no values in memory. In contrast getValues
> will read values from disk if necessary.

So you *could* use a combination of `raster::getValues()` and `raster::setValues()`. As in:

```
raster::setValues(r_pred) <- exp(raster::getValues(r_pred))
```

However, in most cases you can directly use the [`calc` or `stackApply` functions](https://rspatial.org/raster/spatial/8-rastermanip.html#calc). For example:

```
r_back_transformed = raster::calc(r_pred, exp)
```

applies the `exp` functions to all layers of `r_pred`.

However, for a number of functions, raster algebra is natively implemented; from [`raster` documentation chapter four: raster algebra](https://rspatial.org/raster/RasterPackage.pdf)):

> Many generic functions that allow for simple and elegant raster
> algebra have been implemented for Raster* objects, including the
> normal algebraic operators such as +, -, *, /, logical operators such
> as >, >=, <, ==, !} and functions such as abs, round, ceiling, floor,
> trunc, sqrt, log, log10, exp, cos, sin, max, min, range, prod, sum,
> any, all. In these functions you can mix raster objects with numbers,
> as long as the first argument is a raster object.

And you can use `r_back_transformed = exp(r_pred)`.

Finally, `terra::values()` corresponds to `raster::getValues()`/`raster::setValues()` which may explain your initial intuition, and `terra`, the replacement of `raster`,  natively supports some [raster algebra](https://rspatial.org/terra/pkg/4-algebra.html). For non-natively supported functions, `terra::app` maps to `raster::calc`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers by hrvg are good, but I wanted to simplify that and add another approach, and illusrate with example data (from ?predict); and using `terra` (but this also applies to `raster`)

Example data

```
library(terra)
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
names(logo) <- c("red", "green", "blue")
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 
   66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 
   22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)

a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9,
   99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21,
   37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)

xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
e <- extract(logo, xy[,2:3])
v <- data.frame(cbind(pa=xy[,1], e))
```

Model and model prediction

```
library(randomForest)
rfmod <- randomForest(pa ~., data=v)
r_pred <- predict(logo, rfmod)
```

You can now back-transform (I did not actually transform the input) the results like this

```
p <- exp(r_pred)
```

That could be expressed on one line like this

```
p <- predict(logo, rfmod) |> exp()
```

You can also do that like below, but that is not recommended as it is less efficient and not memory safe

```
v <- exp(values(r_pred))
p <- setValues(r_pred, v)

# or overwrite the values like this
# values(r_pred) <- exp(values(r_pred))
```

Or use app (calc with terra)

```
p <- app(r_pred, exp) 
# p <- calc(r_pred, exp)  # with raster
```

Alternatively you could write your own wrapper around the predict function and take care of the transformation there; but that would seem overkill in this instance.

```
f <- function(model, data, ...) {
    exp(predict(model, data, ...))
}
p <- predict(logo, rfmod, fun=f)
```